# Check status of an scheduler task before adding and running another task

Tags: laravel, laravel-scheduler

I have a question about the **task scheduling** in laravel framework. I already have defined the commands `currency:update` and `currency:archive` in the list of console commands. Now, I want to run these two commands in the schedule method but with the following condition:

if this is a time to run the `currency:archive` command, don't run the other command `currency:update` until the previous command (i.e. `currency:archive`) ends; otherwise run the `currency:update` command.

This is my current code in schedule method:

```php
$schedule->command('currency:archive')
         ->dailyAt('00:00')
         ->withoutOverlapping();

$schedule->command('currency:update')
         ->everyMinute()
         ->withoutOverlapping();
```

How should I modify it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the laravel schedule docs the following two features are mentioned:

1. Truth test contraints [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#truth-test-constraints)

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')->daily()->skip(function () {
    return true;
});
```

2. Task hooks [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#task-hooks)

```
$schedule->command('emails:send')
         ->daily()
         ->before(function () {
             // Task is about to start...
         })
         ->after(function () {
             // Task is complete...
         });
```

You could consider setting a variable like `$achriveCommandIsRunning` to true in the `before()` closure. In the `skip()` closure you can `return $archiveCommandIsRunning;` and in the `after()` closure you can set the variable back to false again.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks,

I modified my code as you said and it works now.
Here is the final code:

```
$isArchiveCommandRunning = false;
$schedule->command('currency:archive')
    ->dailyAt('00:00')
    ->before(function () use (&$isArchiveCommandRunning) {
        $isArchiveCommandRunning = true;
    })
    ->after(function () use (&$isArchiveCommandRunning) {
        $isArchiveCommandRunning = false;
    })
    ->withoutOverlapping();

$schedule->command('currency:update')
    ->everyMinute()
    ->skip(function () use (&$isArchiveCommandRunning) {
        return $isArchiveCommandRunning;
    })
    ->withoutOverlapping();
```